# JQuery - Multiple Clickevent show and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

Specifically, I would like to have separate drop-down menus however both click events are opening the same drop down.

I am new to jQuery and would like some help, I have looked at similar forums but I cannot seem to find out specifically to my problem.

I understand I need separate ID for in my js, however, I am unsure how to correctly do it.

```js
$('.Show').click(function() {
    $('#target').show(500);
    $('.Show').hide(0);
    $('.Hide').show(0);
});
$('.Hide').click(function() {
    $('#target').hide(500);
    $('.Show').show(0);
    $('.Hide').hide(0);
});
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    $('#target').slideToggle(1000);
});
$('.toggle2').click(function() {
    $('#target').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#target {

  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  height:160px;
  padding:5px;
  display:none;
}

.Hide {
  display:none;
}
.button {
 font-size: 22px;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Lato';font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
      <div style="width: 600px; float: left; padding-left:20px; padding-top:50px;">
        <div style="font-size:30px; padding-bottom:20px "> JANUARY 2018 </div>
        <button class="toggle button" style="color:rgb(211, 233, 255)">WEEK 1</button>
<div id="target"> <div style="list-style-type:none; width:420px; padding-left:20px"> 
        <li> MONDAY 1ST  </li>
        <li> TUESDAY 2ND  </li>
        <li> WEDNESDAY 3RD  </li>
        <li> THURSDAY 4TH  </li>
        <li> FRIDAY 5TH </li>
        <li> SATURDAY 6TH  </li>
        <li> SUNDAY 7TH  </li> </div>
        </div>
        </div> 
      
          <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
      <div style="width: 600px; float: left; padding-left:20px; padding-top:50px;">
        <button class="toggle2 button" style="color:rgb(211, 233, 255)">WEEK 2</button>
<div id="target"> <div style="list-style-type:none; width:420px; padding-left:20px"> 
        <li> MONDAY 8TH </li>
        <li> TUESDAY 9TH </li>
        <li> WEDNESDAY 10TH </li>
        <li> THURSDAY 11TH </li>
        <li> FRIDAY 12TH</li>
        <li> SATURDAY 13TH  </li>
        <li> SUNDAY 14TH </li> </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have multiple elements with same `id` try changing them to `class` and you can do that by one line by checking the siblings for the `div.target`.

see the demo below

```js
$('.toggle').on('click',function() {
  $(this).siblings('div.target').stop(true,true).slideToggle(1000);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.target {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
}

.Hide {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  font-size: 22px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet'>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Lato';
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 600px; float: left; padding-left:20px; padding-top:50px;">
      <div style="font-size:30px; padding-bottom:20px "> JANUARY 2018 </div>
      <button class="toggle button" style="color:rgb(211, 233, 255)">WEEK 1</button>
      <div class="target">
        <div style="list-style-type:none; width:420px; padding-left:20px">
          <li> MONDAY 1ST </li>
          <li> TUESDAY 2ND </li>
          <li> WEDNESDAY 3RD </li>
          <li> THURSDAY 4TH </li>
          <li> FRIDAY 5TH </li>
          <li> SATURDAY 6TH </li>
          <li> SUNDAY 7TH </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
      <div style="width: 600px; float: left; padding-left:20px; padding-top:50px;">
        <button class="toggle button" style="color:rgb(211, 233, 255)">WEEK 2</button>
        <div class="target">
          <div style="list-style-type:none; width:420px; padding-left:20px">
            <li> MONDAY 8TH </li>
            <li> TUESDAY 9TH </li>
            <li> WEDNESDAY 10TH </li>
            <li> THURSDAY 11TH </li>
            <li> FRIDAY 12TH</li>
            <li> SATURDAY 13TH </li>
            <li> SUNDAY 14TH </li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple elements with the same ID is invalid HTML. Use different IDs instead, just like with `toggle2`:

```js
$('.Show').click(function() {
  $('#target').show(500);
  $('.Show').hide(0);
  $('.Hide').show(0);
});
$('.Hide').click(function() {
  $('#target').hide(500);
  $('.Show').show(0);
  $('.Hide').hide(0);
});
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $('#target').slideToggle(1000);
});
$('.toggle2').click(function() {
  $('#target2').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#target,
#target2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
}

.Hide {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  font-size: 22px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="width: 600px; float: left; padding-left:20px; padding-top:50px;">
    <div style="font-size:30px; padding-bottom:20px "> JANUARY 2018 </div>
    <button class="toggle button" style="color:rgb(211, 233, 255)">WEEK 1</button>
    <div id="target">
      <div style="list-style-type:none; width:420px; padding-left:20px">
        <li> MONDAY 1ST </li>
        <li> TUESDAY 2ND </li>
        <li> WEDNESDAY 3RD </li>
        <li> THURSDAY 4TH </li>
        <li> FRIDAY 5TH </li>
        <li> SATURDAY 6TH </li>
        <li> SUNDAY 7TH </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 600px; float: left; padding-left:20px; padding-top:50px;">
      <button class="toggle2 button" style="color:rgb(211, 233, 255)">WEEK 2</button>
      <div id="target2">
        <div style="list-style-type:none; width:420px; padding-left:20px">
          <li> MONDAY 8TH </li>
          <li> TUESDAY 9TH </li>
          <li> WEDNESDAY 10TH </li>
          <li> THURSDAY 11TH </li>
          <li> FRIDAY 12TH</li>
          <li> SATURDAY 13TH </li>
          <li> SUNDAY 14TH </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

But it would be cleaner to select the `target` *from* the context of the clicked `toggle`, and use classes instead of IDs, like this:

```js
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  const target = $(this.nextElementSibling);
  target.slideToggle(1000);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#target,
#target2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
}

.Hide {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  font-size: 22px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="width: 600px; float: left; padding-left:20px; padding-top:50px;">
    <div style="font-size:30px; padding-bottom:20px "> JANUARY 2018 </div>
    <button class="toggle button" style="color:rgb(211, 233, 255)">WEEK 1</button>
    <div id="target">
      <div style="list-style-type:none; width:420px; padding-left:20px">
        <li> MONDAY 1ST </li>
        <li> TUESDAY 2ND </li>
        <li> WEDNESDAY 3RD </li>
        <li> THURSDAY 4TH </li>
        <li> FRIDAY 5TH </li>
        <li> SATURDAY 6TH </li>
        <li> SUNDAY 7TH </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 600px; float: left; padding-left:20px; padding-top:50px;">
      <button class="toggle button" style="color:rgb(211, 233, 255)">WEEK 2</button>
      <div id="target2">
        <div style="list-style-type:none; width:420px; padding-left:20px">
          <li> MONDAY 8TH </li>
          <li> TUESDAY 9TH </li>
          <li> WEDNESDAY 10TH </li>
          <li> THURSDAY 11TH </li>
          <li> FRIDAY 12TH</li>
          <li> SATURDAY 13TH </li>
          <li> SUNDAY 14TH </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```